# undefined symbols when loading C++ shared lib within a shared C++ lib, which itself is loaded by python

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I have been working on a piece of new code within ESPResSo++ (http://www.espresso-pp.de/), a molecular dynamic (MD) simulation package. The code connects ESPResSo++ with PLUMED (https://plumed.github.io/), a plugin for MD packages. ESPResSo++ has extensive uses of boost-python library. The Python code loads a shared C++ library that does most of the computing, while providing an interface to users. The PLUMED library is called from the shared C++ library of ESPResSo++. PLUMED can be statically linked to ESPResSo++, or dynamically, or at runtime. When PLUMED is linked statically, I have had no issues. When ESPResSo++ is built with runtime linking of PLUMED, the undefined symbol error arises:

```
+++ Loading the PLUMED kernel runtime +++
+++ PLUMED_KERNEL="/home/theorie/songbin/applications/src/plumed-2.4.0/src/lib/libplumedKernel.so" +++
+++ PLUMED kernel not found ! +++
+++ error message from dlopen(): /home/theorie/songbin/applications/src/plumed-2.4.0/src/lib/libplumedKernel.so: undefined symbol: plumed_cmd
+++ ERROR: you are trying to use plumed, but it is not available +++
+++ Check your PLUMED_KERNEL environment variable +++
```

. I ran

```
ldd -r libplumedKernel.so
```

. Among the output is:

```
undefined symbol: plumed_cmd    (./libplumedKernel.so)
undefined symbol: plumed_kernel_register    (./libplumedKernel.so)
undefined symbol: plumed_finalize   (./libplumedKernel.so)
undefined symbol: plumed_create (./libplumedKernel.so)
```

. Then I ran

```
nm _espressopp.so | grep plumed
```

. I got

```
000000000275b8a0 T plumed_c2f
000000000275b660 T plumed_cmd
000000000275b5d0 T plumed_create
000000000275b450 T plumed_dummy_cmd
000000000275b430 T plumed_dummy_create
000000000275b440 T plumed_dummy_finalize
000000000275b900 T plumed_f2c
000000000275ba30 T plumed_f_cmd
000000000275bc20 T plumed_f_cmd_
000000000275bc30 T plumed_f_cmd__
000000000275ba10 T plumed_f_create
000000000275bbd0 T plumed_f_create_
000000000275bbe0 T plumed_f_create__
000000000275ba60 T plumed_f_finalize
000000000275bc70 T plumed_f_finalize_
000000000275bc80 T plumed_f_finalize__
000000000275b9f0 T plumed_f_gcmd
000000000275bae0 T plumed_f_gcmd_
000000000275baf0 T plumed_f_gcmd__
000000000275b9e0 T plumed_f_gcreate
000000000275ba90 T plumed_f_gcreate_
000000000275baa0 T plumed_f_gcreate__
000000000275ba00 T plumed_f_gfinalize
000000000275bb30 T plumed_f_gfinalize_
000000000275bb40 T plumed_f_gfinalize__
000000000275b9a0 T plumed_f_ginitialized
000000000275bb80 T plumed_f_ginitialized_
000000000275bb90 T plumed_f_ginitialized__
000000000275ba80 T plumed_f_global
000000000275bd10 T plumed_f_global_
000000000275bd20 T plumed_f_global__
000000000275b700 T plumed_finalize
000000000275b960 T plumed_f_installed
000000000275bcc0 T plumed_f_installed_
000000000275bcd0 T plumed_f_installed__
000000000275b800 T plumed_gcmd
000000000275b7c0 T plumed_gcreate
000000000275b840 T plumed_gfinalize
000000000275b890 T plumed_ginitialized
000000000275b7b0 T plumed_global
000000000275b790 T plumed_installed
000000000275b4a0 T plumed_kernel_register
```

I don't understand why the error happens. As 'plumed_cmd' and others are defined in _espressopp.so, yet they cannot be found when loading libplumedKernel.so. If someone can help resolve this issue, I'd appreciate it.

**Update 1**
I found this page (http://grokbase.com/t/python/python-list/071afrstds/dynamic-library-loading-missing-symbols), and learned that I could set LD_DEBUG=all to find out symbol searching during execution. Similarly as in the webpage, the _espressopp.so was not searched for the symbols. This was because dlopen uses RTLD_NOW as flag when importing _espressopp.so. The page suggested using RTLD_GLOBAL as flags. Unfortunately, it causes import failures elsewhere. I cannot focus on this right now, the code does work with static or dynamic linking instead of runtime linking. Plumed does have an interface, which I think could be wrapped by Boost/Python somehow to achieve runtime linking. But it is not a priority for me. If someone has suggestions, please post below this message. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try putting "_espressopp.so" in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

Comment: Infact all the necessary libraries should be on LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: I have tried adding the directory of _espressopp.so to  LD_LIBRARY_PATH. It is the same issue.

Comment: Oh ... then may be you have to load _espressopp.so also just like libplumedKernel.so . This will bring them in to same name space and they can find eachother. I am not sure of this though !

Comment: _espressopp.so is loaded by Python. Can I load libplumedKernel.so with Python, even though it is a C++ code without Python bindings? Sorry if this is a stupid question. I don't fully understand what I am doing.

Comment: By the way, I am using Boost 1.61.

Comment: Your libplumedKernel.so and other libraries should be linked against _espressopp.so and not rely on some other code loading it. ldd libplumedKernel.so should show _espressopp.so.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved by change of code in upstream (PLUMED). The details of change: https://github.com/plumed/plumed2/pull/362. In short, PLUMED no longer relies on dlopen to search the library. Instead it uses dlsym find symbols that are not visible globally.